# Instanciar una clase a partir de un método diferente del constructor

Tags: javascript, java

Según he leído en el libro 'Clean Code' de Uncle Bob, se recomienda lo siguiente:
'Al sobrecargar constructores, use métodos de factoría estáticos con nombres que describan los argumentos'. Por ejemplo:

```
Complex fulcrumPoint = Complex.FromRealNumber(23.0);
```

Es mejor que:

```
Complex fulcrumPoint = new Complex(23.0);
```

¿Cómo debería de ser el código de la clase Complex para poder realizarla según el primer supuesto?
Al igual que con Java, ¿cómo se podría implementar con JavaScript?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí te dejo unos breves ejemplos de cómo podría ser esa clase con comentarios en el código, cualquier duda pregunta!

**Java**

```
public class Complex {

    private double value;

    public Complex(){
    }

    /**
     * Método estático que permite construir objetos a partir de un doble
     * @param value double con el valor que queremos que tenga el objeto
     * @return nuevo objeto Complex con el valor asignado
     */
    public static Complex FromRealNumber(double value){
        Complex complex = new Complex();//Creo un nuevo objeto
        complex.value = value;/*Le asigno value directamente
         aunque sea private puedo modificarlo porque sigo dentro de la clase*/
        return complex;
    }

    //****************************** Setter y getter
    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        //Sobreescribiendo el toString puedo imprimir el objeto y obtendré este mensaje
        return "Este Complex tiene un valor de " + value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Complex c = Complex.FromRealNumber(24.9);
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

**JavaScript**

```js
//Declaración de la clase
class Complex{

    //Constructor
    constructor(){
        this._value = 0;
    }
    //Método estático para construirlo con el valor indicado
    static FromRealNumber(value){
        var complex = new Complex();
        complex._value = value;//Asigno el valor y lo devuelvo
        return complex;
    }
    //toString para imprimirlo
    toString(){
        return "Este Complex tiene un valor de " + this._value;
    }
}

var c = Complex.FromRealNumber(43.3);
console.log(c.toString());
```

Comment: Es decir, en ambos casos, independientemente de la existencia de constructor, si tu llamas al método FromRealNumber(), crea la instancia de Complex no? El libro también recomienda 'privatizar' el constructor para así evitar llamarlo...

Comment: Efectivamente, se puede privatizar el constructor (al menos en java) para evitar que sea llamado, así solo se podrán crear objetos a través del "constructor estático" o factory que hayas diseñado.

Answer (score 0):

Para la parte de Java solo sería necesario hacer algo así:

```
public static Complex FromRealNumber(double n) {
  return new Complex(n);
}
```

Simplemente en el método estático creas un objeto nuevo de la clase Complex y lo devuelves.

Para la parte de JavaScript no tiene mucho sentido lo que propones, porque en JavaScript no se puede sobrecargar una función. Si defines una función con el mismo nombre:

```js
function a() {
  console.log("Sin parametros");
}

function a(n) {
  console.log("Con parámetros");
}

new a();
new a(1);
```

Fíjate si ejecutas esto, a lo mejor te esperarías que se escribiese "Sín parámetros" y a continuación "Con parámetros". Pero eso no pasa, y escribe dos veces "Con parámetros" porque al definir dos veces una función con el mismo nombre, la segunda sobreescribe a la primera.

Además en JavaScript los parámetros no van tipados, no se indica el tipo de los parámetros en la definición de las funciones, por lo que en el caso de que se pudiese sobrecargar la función, no se sabría cual versión de la funciona utilizar, al no poderse determinar el tipo de parámetro. Por lo que al final, vas a acabar necesitando funciones con nombres diferentes.

Más info:

- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456177/function-overloading-in-javascript-best-practices/457589#:~:text=There%20is%20no%20real%20function,and%20what%20type%20they%20are.&text=The%20correct%20answer%20is%20THERE%20IS%20NO%20OVERLOADING%20IN%20JAVASCRIPT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456177/function-overloading-in-javascript-best-practices/457589#:%7E:text=There%20is%20no%20real%20function,and%20what%20type%20they%20are.&text=The%20correct%20answer%20is%20THERE%20IS%20NO%20OVERLOADING%20IN%20JAVASCRIPT).
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694588/method-overloading-in-javascript

Comment: En verdad no necesitas sobrecargar los constructores ya que has puesto el factory dentro de la propia clase,  tienes completo acceso a las variables privadas.